# Razor Kendo Date Range Controls not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, telerik

I cannot get the kendo datepicker to save the values in the model on submit.  When i submit the values are 1/1/0011.  What am I missing??

Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!
Extra text so I can clear the error your post looks like mostly code!!!!

**View Code**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"> <strong>Check availability</strong></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label for="start">Start date:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartDate)
              .Name("start")
              .Value(DateTime.Now)
          .Min(DateTime.Now)
         .Max(DateTime.Now.AddYears(2))
              .Events(e => e.Change("startChange")))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        <label for="end" style="margin-left: 3em">End date:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.EndDate)
              .Name("end")
              .Value(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
       .Min(DateTime.Now)
      .Max(DateTime.Now.AddYears(2))
              .Events(e => e.Change("endChange")))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        <input type="submit" value="Request These Dates" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**`Controller method`**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Details([Bind(Include = "ID,ProductName,ProductDescription,ProductPrice,DisplayOrder,Quantity,StartDate,EndDate")] Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for(DateTime date = product.StartDate; date <= product.EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                product.ReservedDates.Add(new ReservedDate(){Date = date, ProductID = product.ID});
            }
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

**Model properties**

```
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really imporatant to keep in sync the kendo.culture (the one in the browser) and the server culture (the one that the ModelBinder uses). This will avoid problems when it comes to number and DateTime parsing.

How to keep them in tact is covered [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/globalization#use-the-same-culture-on-the-server-and-client-side).

Comment: Would this be true when running in a dev environment?  It still does not explain the dates. 1/1/0011.  I believe that is the default date if you do not set it.